# Array search algorithms for largest group of elements based on value

Tags: python, search, matrix, array-algorithms

I need a search algorithm that can find the largest rectangle of mostly 1's in a matrix of 0s and 1s; specifically, I need it to return the (x,y) coordinate pairs of the top-left and bottom-right of these rectangles.

For example, consider the following matrix:

```
[1,1,0,0,0,
 1,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,1,1,
 0,0,0,1,1]
```

If I set the threshold to 75% (average value of the rectangle is 0.75), two rectangles (squares, specifically) would be found at the top left and bottom right of the matrix. And the tuple outputs would top left (x,y), bottom right (x,y) for each point.

```
{rectangle_1: ((0,0),(1,1)),
rectangle_2: ((3,3),(4,4))}
```

Are there any array/matrix search algorithms that I should consider as a starting point for this task?

If it's of any importance, I'll be using python. So if such an algorithm has a python implementation, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using NumPy? Some more context would be good.

Comment: How big are you expecting these matrices to be?

Comment: @TedBrownlow , I'm expecting [15x15] to [20x20] sized matrices

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, numpy is my intention. I figure that's my fastest option; certainly better than nested lists.

Comment: @j9000 Alright, I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

My take on the problem - I converted the matrix to dictionary with keys as positions (x, y) and values equal to 0 or 1 (surely, this is *not* the fastest approach - you are surely better with NumPy):

```
from itertools import count

lst = [
 1,1,0,0,0,
 1,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,1,1,
 0,0,0,1,1]

def get_values(d, i1, j1, i2, j2):
    c = 0
    s = 0
    for i in range(i1, i2+1):
        for j in range(j1, j2+1):
            s += d[(i, j)]
            c += 1
    return s / c

def find_squares(lst, m, n, t):
    lst = iter(lst)
    d = {(j, i): next(lst) for i in range(m) for j in range(n)}

    seen_squares = []

    for i1 in range(m):
        for j1 in range(n):
            ii2 = count(i1+1)
            ij2 = count(j1+1)

            i2 = next(ii2)
            j2 = next(ij2)
            current_square = None
            while i2 < m and j2 < n:
                if get_values(d, i1, j1, i2, j2) >= t:
                    current_square = i1, j1, i2, j2
                else:
                    break

                i2 = next(ii2)
                j2 = next(ij2)

            if current_square:
                for x1, y1, x2, y2 in seen_squares:
                    if i1 >= x1 and i2 - 1  <= x2 and j1 >= y1 and j2 - 1 <= y2:
                        break
                else:
                    seen_squares.append(current_square)
                    yield current_square

for i1, j1, i2, j2 in find_squares(lst, 5, 5, 0.75):
    print(i1, j1, i2, j2)
```

Prints:

```
0 0 1 1
3 3 4 4
```

For matrix:

```
lst = [
 1,1,0,0,0,
 1,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,1,1,
 0,0,0,1,1,
 0,0,0,1,1]
```

The output is:

```
0 0 1 1
3 2 4 3
3 3 4 4
```